# Compare one directory at time 1 to same directory at time 2

Tags: python, compare, directory-structure, analyzer

My goal : compare the content of one directory (including sub-directories and files) at time 1 to the content of the same directory at time 2 (e.g. 6 months later). "Content" means : number and names of the subdirectories + number and names and size of files. The main intended outcome is : being sure that no files were destroyed or corrupted in the mean time.
I did not find any existing tool, although I was wondering whether https://github.com/njanakiev/folderstats [folderstats](https://github.com/njanakiev/folderstats) could help.
Would you have any suggestion of modules or anything to start well? If you heard about an existing tool for this, I would also be interested.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [`filecmp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html#module-filecmp) it has a [`dircmp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html#the-dircmp-class) class that compares directorys and it's in the included lib.

Comment: how about create a git repository, use `git init && git add . && git commit init`, you can check status change 6 months later by `git status`

Comment: See [Watch a Directory for Changes](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html).

Comment: @Jab Your suggestion seems good to compare two directories, not one directory at time 1 and at time 2.

Comment: @KevenLi Your suggestion (create a repository) seems at first glance too elaborated for my need.

Comment: @martineau I think this is the good direction, I have to check. Thanks to you all. Other suggestions welcome :)

Comment: silfer1200: Obviously I agree. You will need to extend the technique to support sub-directories, and for that I suggest using `os.walk()` instead of `os.listdir()`. It would also be relatively easy to extend since the result is a dictionary whose values are all `None`—which could be replaced with the file's `os.stat()` to support detecting changes to existing files (as well as sub-directories if done properly).

Comment: @martineau : your new comment is very useful, thanks again. I will try from tomorrow on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that should help to get you started. It defines a function that will build a data structure of nested dictionaries that correspond the contents of the starting root directory and everything below it in the filesystem. Each each item dictionary that has with a `'type'` key with the value `'file'`, will also have a `'stat'` key that can contain whatever file metadata you want or need, such as time of creation, last modification time, length in bytes, … etc.

You can use it to obtain a "before" and "after" snapshots of the directory you're tracking and use them for comparison purposes. I've left the latter (the comparing) out since I'm not sure exactly what you're interested in.

Note that when I actually went about implementing this, I found it simpler to write a recursive function than to use `os.walk()`, as I suggested in a comment.

The following implements a version of the function and prints out the data structure of nested dictionaries it returns.

```
import os
from pathlib import PurePath


def path_to_dict(path):
    result = {}
    result['full_path'] = PurePath(path).as_posix()
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        result['type'] = 'dir'
        result['items'] = {filename: path_to_dict(os.path.join(path, filename))
                               for filename in os.listdir(path)}
    else:
        result['type'] = 'file'
        result['stat'] = 'os.stat(path)'  # Preserve any needed metadata.
    return result


root = './folder'  # Change as desired.
before = path_to_dict(root)

# Pretty-print data structure created.
from pprint import pprint
pprint(before, sort_dicts=False)
```